# final static vs final non-static fields and JVM optimization

Tags: java, optimization, static, jvm, final

I'm curious how are the `static` `final` fields treated by the JVM. I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485290/final-static-vs-non-final-static-variable) but it's not what I'm looking for. Let's consider such example:

```
public class TestClassX {
   public final int CODE_A = 132;
   public final int CODE_B = 948;
   public final int CODE_C = 288;
   // some other code
}

public class TestClassY {
   public static final int CODE_A = 132;
   public static final int CODE_B = 948;
   public static final int CODE_C = 288;
   // some other code
}
```

In `TestClassX` fields, as they are `final` and cannot be modified, have the same values in all instances of the `TestClassX` class. Of course I cannot write `TestClassX.CODE_A` but I can say, that these values are actually common for all instances - I'm sure, that each instance has a `CODE_A` field with the value `132`.

In the `TestClassY` I can use the syntax `TestClassY.CODE_A`, but at a first sight it's only easier for a developer who sees "Oh, those values are common for all instances".

**My main question:** 
I guess that JVM, in case of `TestClassX`, doesn't use any extra memory for `final` fields each time a new instance is created. Does it? Does JVM make any optimization in this case and what kind of optimization it is?

Extra question 1) I'm also sure that I'm missing something very important here which is the cause of my doubts. What's that?

Extra question 2) Btw. How can I take a look at how my Java source code looks like after the JVM optimization (so I can use in in the future ;))? Does any IDE support such a functionality? IntelliJ for example? I would like simply to see how JVM treats my `TestClassX` and `TestClassY`.

Comment: related - javac always inlines constant instance variables, probably a bug:) - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-lang-fans/AyS3UqX4lj4

Comment: 2) The JVM's optimizations aren't done in a way that lends itself to being expressed as Java source.  Compilers optimize an internal representation of what the code *does*.  source->source optimizers usually only exist for languages that have to be compiled every time they're used (e.g. javascript).  Your actual goal here should be covered by looking at the Java byte-code, or the asm resulting from JIT-compiling for a specific CPU.  (Or traditional ahead-of-time compiling for Java implementations like gcj`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Non-static fields are always present in the instances. They do not save memory.
- In general JVM does not optimize non-static fields. Even if they are final they can be still set to different value using reflection or during deserialization.
- There is an experimental VM option `-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields` (off by default) which tells JVM to optimize access to such fields, i.e. treat them as constants and eliminate field loads.
- There is a [`-XX:+PrintAssembly`](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PrintAssembly) VM option to dump JIT-compiled code.

Comment: Thanks that you mentioned about reflection and deserialization. And for TrustFinalNonStaticFields option - I didn't know! ... ^

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4279442/5089400) can help you.

For the second part you could see the generated assembly (as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1503919/5089400)) by adding `-XX:+PrintOptoAssembly` flag when you run/compile your code.

I should also add that the assembly code given to you is not the real opcode generated by the jvm, but the code needed to be run under your 
actual architecture.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for not posting that as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to do so...