# Groovy singleton thread safe

Tags: groovy, thread-safety, singleton

Does @Singleton annotation in Groovy make a singleton thread-safe?

If it's not, which is the easiest way to create a thread-safe singleton using Groovy?

Comment: You mean does it make all the methods in your class thread safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual class used as the instance is **not** threadsafe (unless you make it).  There are lots of examples around here (e.g. [Are final static variables thread safe in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412124/are-final-static-variables-thread-safe-in-java): a static final `HashMap` is used there, which is not threadsafe)

The **creation** of the singleton using groovys `@Singleton` annotation is thread-safe (and you should rely on that).

The [docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Singleton+transformation) show two versions, of the corresponding Java code generated by the transformation:

1. Here is the regular version `@Singleton`, which results in a `static final` variable, which again is threadsafe in java:

   > ```
   > public class T {
   >     public static final T instance = new T();
   >     private T() {}
   > }
   > ```
2. For the `lazy` version (`@Singleton(lazy=true)`) [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) is created:

   > ```
   > class T {
   >     private static volatile T instance
   >     private T() {}
   >     static T getInstance () {
   >         if (instance) {
   >             instance
   >         } else {
   >             synchronized(T) {
   >                 if (instance) {
   >                     instance
   >                 } else {
   >                     instance = new T ()
   >                 }
   >             }
   >         }
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

For reference, here is a [gist with a simple class and the disassembled code](https://gist.github.com/christoph-frick/118857c176c3f06efa16)